# Thread and public void run() method in java

Tags: java

```
    public Thread thread = new Thread();

    public void start() {
        running = true;
        thread.start();
    }

public void run() {

    while(running) {

        System.out.println("test");

        try {
            thread.sleep(1000);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

}
```

My problem is that the program will not print out "test" nor will it seem to loop despite 'running' being true. Is there a way I can continuously loop in the run method?

Comment: Does the ``run()`` method you show actually belong to the actual Thread-subclass you start?

Answer (score 2):

You haven't actually asked `run()` to be called. All you've done is declare a `run()` method unrelated to the `Thread`.

Put your `run()` method in a `Runnable` and pass that to the `Thread`.

```
public Thread thread = new Thread(new Runnable() {

    public void run() {

        while (running) {

            System.out.println("test");

            try {
                thread.sleep(1000);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

    }
});
```

Comment: if class implements Runnable: 'Thread name = new Thread(this);' . If not, change 'this' to the name of your runnable. You need to pass your runnable to a thread.

Edit: commented on the wrong post. Sorry, on my phome, hard to navigate.

Answer (score 2):

The problem appears to be that you aren't running the `run` method that you think you're running in the thread.

First, you've created a `Thread` called `thread`.  In your class's `start` method, you set `running` to `true` and call `thread.start()`.  But that just calls [`Thread`'s `run()` method, which does nothing](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.html#run%28%29).

> public void run()
>
> If this thread was constructed using a separate
>   Runnable run object, then that Runnable object's run method is called;
>   otherwise, this method does nothing and returns.

You aren't calling your own `run` method.

You have created a `run` method.  I can't see your class definition here, but I'm assuming that your class implements `Runnable`.  You need to send an instance of your class as an argument to the `Thread`, by using the [`Thread` constructor that takes a `Runnable`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.html#Thread%28java.lang.Runnable%29).  Then the `Thread` will know to run your `Runnable`'s `run()` method.

Answer (score 0):

Well you need to call `start()` to start the thread. Otherwise neither `running` will  be true
nor `thread.start()` get executed. Well i can guess you were intended to do something like this:

```
class MyTask implements Runnable
{
   boolean running = false;
   public void start() {
        running = true;
        new Thread(this).start();
    }

public void run() {

    while(running) {

        System.out.println("test");

        try {
            Thread.sleep(1000); 
              // you were doing thread.sleep()! sleep is a static function
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

}

  public static void main(String[] args)
  {
     new MyTask().start();
  }
}
```